# Android menu item show up correctly on pad but disappear in cell phone

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have a menu item on the actionbar and I test to find this item shows correctly on a pad(8 inch screen, android 4.2) but does not show up on the cell phone(4 inch screen, android 4.3).

Here is the screen shot.See the top-right corner.

[pad which is right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncH6l.png)

[cell phone which is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG39U.png)

And the XML code here obviously the same.Is there anything I missed?

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/settings"
  android:orderInCategory="100"
  android:title="@string/action_settings"
  app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: did you try showAsAction="always" ?

Comment: what is the version of your phone

Comment: Tried and it shows correctly with the title text. Actually I want to show this when user touch the item, so I use "nerver" and this goes wrong.

Comment: Android 4.2 vs 4.3 nearly the same, I don't think this makes different.